# Filter a vector of strings based on string matching

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
X <- c("mama.log", "papa.log", "mimo.png", "mentor.log")
```

How do I retrieve another vector that only contains elements starting with "m" and ending with ".log"?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

you can use `grepl` with regular expression:

```
X[grepl("^m.*\\.log", X)]
```

Comment: As Andrey asked for a pattern to match strings *ending* in .log, I believe this should be X[grepl("^m.*\\.log$", X)]

Comment: Exactly. I just missed it. It should end with `$`.

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
grep("^m.*[.]log$", X, value = TRUE)
## [1] "mama.log"   "mentor.log"
```

A variation of this is to use a glob rather than a regular expression:

```
grep(glob2rx("m*.log"), X, value = TRUE)
## [1] "mama.log"   "mentor.log"
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of glob2rx, it's great!

Comment: `value = TRUE` very nice & helpful

Answer (score 22):

The documentation on the `stringr` package says:

> `str_subset()` is a wrapper around `x[str_detect(x, pattern)]`, and is equivalent to `grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE)`. `str_which()` is a wrapper around `which(str_detect(x, pattern))`, and is equivalent to `grep(pattern, x)`.

So, in your case, the more elegant way to accomplish your task using `tidyverse` instead of base R is as following.

```
library(tidyverse)

c("mama.log", "papa.log", "mimo.png", "mentor.log") %>% 
   str_subset(pattern = "^m.*\\.log")
```

which produces the output:

```
[1] "mama.log"   "mentor.log"
```

Comment: You only need to load the `library(stringr)` instead of the whole tidyverse packages.

Answer (score 1):

Using pipes...

```
library(tidyverse)

c("mama.log", "papa.log", "mimo.png", "mentor.log") %>%
 .[grepl("^m.*\\.log$", .)]
[1] "mama.log"   "mentor.log"
```

Comment: This adds nothing; it's just an alternate syntax for the function provided in kohske's answer. People who know how to use pipes should know how to adapt the syntax already, and people who don't know hot to use pipes would be confused by this answer as it offers no explanation.

Comment: But even with a brief explanation of pipes, if someone asked a question "How do I find the average of a vector `x`", and someone answers `mean(x)`, `x %>% mean` is not a different answer.

Comment: Correct. They are not ever *needed*, they are just a matter of style. And using them or not does not change the solution, which is "use `grepl` with these arguments...".

Comment: I think I need them because I use them often, therefore I added the answer for those who prefer to use pipes.