# dplyr / tidy way to filter a vector based on a substring?

Tags: r, dplyr

We can see some good examples of how to [filter a data.frame based on a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filtering-row-which-contains-a-certain-string-using-dplyr); is there a *tidy* way of doing this for a ***vector***? (that is, without [using `grepl()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187442/filter-a-vector-of-strings-based-on-string-matching) or similar)

#### Example

I tried what would work on a data.frame

```
# Leave only words that don't begin with 'cat'

vec <- c("cat", "catamaran", "dog", "mouse", "catacombs")

vec %>% filter(substr(1, 3) != "cat") # %>% ... etc
```

but

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

#### Note

We could use something like `vec %>% { .[!grepl("cat", .)] }`, or more accurately `vec %>% { .[substr(., 1, 3) != "cat"]}`, but I will try to find something that..

1. is more beginner friendly, with more verbally descriptive functions (e.g. a complete novice can probably guess what 'filter' does but possibly not 'grepl')
2. has less finicky syntax (as few `{` and `}` as possible)
3. pipes more elegantly (e.g. `vec %>% filter(...) %>% next operations`)
4. contains as little repetition as possible, noting that the `grepl` way uses the original vector (denoted by `.`) twice (as opposed to just once which would be ideal)

Answer (score 11):

I think `tidyverse` is more suitable for dataframes/lists and not for vectors. Pipes are needed if you want to perform more than one operation but here you can get the expected result using a single function (`grep`) without any need for pipes.

```
grep('^cat', vec, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
#[1] "dog"   "mouse"
```

---

Or maybe convert the vector to dataframe and then use either of

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

vec %>% enframe() %>% filter(!startsWith(value, 'cat'))
```

Or

```
vec %>% enframe() %>% filter_at(vars(value), any_vars(!startsWith(., 'cat')))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using a different package, you can use the `stri_detect_fixed` function from the `stringi` package.

```
install.packages('stringi')
library(stringi)

vec <- c("cat", "catamaran", "dog", "mouse", "catacombs")
vec[stri_detect_fixed(vec, 'cat')]
```

Output:

```
[1] "cat"       "catamaran" "catacombs"
```

You should then be able to pipe this to what ever commands you would like.

Answer (score 5):

Using `purrr` to work with vectors

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

vec <- c("cat", "catamaran", "dog", "mouse", "catacombs")
vec %>% discard(.p=str_detect, pattern = "^cat")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyverse`, we can convert it to `tibble`, use `str_detect` within `filter` and `pull` the values

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(vec) %>%
      filter(!str_detect(vec, "^cat")) %>%
      pull(vec)
#[1] "dog"   "mouse"
```

---

Or with `magrittr`

```
vec %>%
     str_detect("^cat") %>%
     `!` %>%
     magrittr::extract(vec, .)
#[1] "dog"   "mouse"
```