# How to filter through a vector a files and return a new vector that only has those contain ".html" on R

Tags: r

I tried using

```
files1 <- str_detect(files, "html")
```

but all that returns is the list as a boolean which I do not want.

Comment: Several options here: [Filter a vector of strings based on string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187442/filter-a-vector-of-strings-based-on-string-matching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `str_subset`

```
library(stringr0
str_subset(files, "html")
```

---

Or use the logical output from 'str_detect' as index to extract the corresponding elements

```
files[str_detect(files, "html")]
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R way, notice argument `value`.

```
grep("\\.html", files, value = TRUE)
```